# Passing arguments containing non-ASCII characters from bash to a Java program

Tags: java, bash, character-encoding, command-line-arguments

Is it possible to reliably pass non-ASCII characters as command-line arguments from `bash` on *CentOS*? I **keep getting wrongly encoded chars** form the `args`.

In my case it's a pesky ASCII **85h** character which is defined only for [Cp1250](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250) but not for UTF-8 or ISO-8859-*.

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS= read -r -n 10 -d '' ARG < "$INPUT_FILE"

java -jar foo.jar "$ARG"
```

The shell's `LANG`/`LC_*` can't be set to Cp1250. I guess this might the culprit, right? The shell kinda tries to pass it in a "binary way" but apparently fails.

AFAIK, the `-Dfile.encoding` can be used to override JVM's detected shell charset in `args`. Is this relevant? I've tried that but no luck here.

Comment: What error are you getting? As far as I can tell, this isn't a `bash` problem. `ARG` will contain the bytes contained in the file and pass them literally to `java`. That would make `foo.jar` the entity trying to interpret CP1250-encoded text as UTF-8-encoded text

Comment: @chepner Yea, so can I force `foo.jar` to interpret the bytes passed in `args[]` as Cp1250 instead of UTF-8? It seemed the `-Dfile.encoding` might do this.

Comment: @chepner Added an error description.